# Why can't I install Cassandra-driver

Tags: python, database, cassandra

I am studying Cassandra by its document.
But when I use "pip install cassandra-driver" to install cassandra-driver ,failed like this:

```html
weikairen2@weikairen2-virtual-machine:~$ pip install cassandra-driver
Collecting cassandra-driver
  Using cached cassandra-driver-3.7.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.6 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cassandra-driver)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): futures in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cassandra-driver)
Building wheels for collected packages: cassandra-driver
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cassandra-driver ... 




^Z
[1]+  已停止               pip install cassandra-driver
weikairen2@weikairen2-virtual-machine:~$ ls
cassandra               jdk              公共的  图片  音乐
cassandra-driver-3.7.0  pycharm          模板    文档  桌面
examples.desktop        PycharmProjects  视频    下载
weikairen2@weikairen2-virtual-machine:~$ cd cassandra-driver-3.7.0
weikairen2@weikairen2-virtual-machine:~/cassandra-driver-3.7.0$ ls
cassandra                  ez_setup.py  MANIFEST.in  README.rst  setup.py
cassandra_driver.egg-info  LICENSE      PKG-INFO     setup.cfg
weikairen2@weikairen2-virtual-machine:~/cassandra-driver-3.7.0$ python setup.py install

^Z
[2]+  已停止               python setup.py install
weikairen2@weikairen2-virtual-machine:~/cassandra-driver-3.7.0$ python setup.py build
```

as you can see,there is no response 
and I have to stop it by ctrl+z

I also tried manul install 
no response again

So where is the error? How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266

Comment: Just thought I'd jump in - I had to install cassandra-driver as a dependency just now and it took like 5 minutes...

Answer (score 26):

I figure out

"sudo pip install cassandra-driver"

it takes a little long time
I was just too impatient

Comment: Thanks, I kept killing it, thinking it was hung and couldn't possibly be that slow. NumPy used to be this slow to build in the 80s. Prepare to go get a pizza before installing the Cassandra driver.

Comment: same happened for me, i was killing the build continuously. I thought problem with the package. But after 4-5 minutes got "successfully installed" message :-)

Comment: @RubanrajRavichandran 4-5 minutes is too good. My ubuntu VM(1GB RAM,40GB HD) is took more than 3 hours and then i quit.

Comment: My laptop configuration is, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, and i5 7th gen processor. You could try with increase your VM configuration. :-) @khalid

Comment: @KhalidUsman 4-5 mins could be realistic. I installed it in my i5 laptop running Linux. In 'top' I saw 'cc1' and 'as' processes, so it must have been compiling some C and assembly code (but used just 1 CPU core at a time).

Comment: Datastax have added some comments to speed up the compile time  https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.14/installation/

Answer (score 3):

It takes a long time, ~10mins in some environments. You can use

```
$ # installing from source
$ CASS_DRIVER_BUILD_CONCURRENCY=8 python setup.py install
$ # installing from pip
$ CASS_DRIVER_BUILD_CONCURRENCY=8 pip install cassandra-driver
```

to speed it up.

Source: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.25/installation/

Comment: this accelerated the process a lot. thanks.